# INSERT INTO table using OpenQuery

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

i have two database **MSSQL** and **MYSQL**

i want to transfer data from MYSQL to MSSQL, in a result i made Linked Servers between them

I don't have any problem until this step

I wrote below code for fetch data from MYSQL and insert to MSSQL

```
INSERT into dbo.test2016
SELECT * FROM openquery(test1, 'SELECT t_id,t_date
FROM test1.test2016') T1
INNER JOIN dbo.test2016 T2 ON T1.t_date > T2.t_date
```

but I face **Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1** in **MSSQL**
because of **INNER JOIN** can't match with **INSERT INTO**

i need before insert to MSSQL, compare t_date column between two table

how can i do?

Comment: Consider exporting your data from MySQL to flat files and importing into SQL Server.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i made linked servers between these database that automatically this task do not manually

Answer (score 9):

I know that this thread is old but I figured that I share an example that worked for me.

```
insert into openquery([LinkedServerName],'Select column1, column2 from mysqlDatabase.tableName' ) 
select column1, column2 from msServerTableName
```